# Upload XML file to server on another machine

Tags: upload, remote-server, basex

How can I upload a XML file that resides on a computer (let's call it *workstation*) onto a BaseX server that runs on another computer (*server*)?

To upload a XML file to the BaseX server on *workstation* I use

```
basexclient -n localhost -d -w -c "CREATE DATABASE ${db_name} ${file}"
```

When the hostname is changed from `localhost` to `server`, this command fails with

```
org.basex.core.BaseXException: Resource "[complete FILE path]" not found.
```

IIUC, the error happens because this command does not upload the XML file itself, but just asks the server to read it from the path `${file}`. The command then fails because `${file}` is not available on *server* but only on *workstation*.

What command should I use to upload the XML file to the remote server?

*(Obviously without copying the file to the server and then executing the command locally on the server.)*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that -n means what you seem to be using it to mean, and that a local client can in fact communicate with a remote server, and assuming also that your XML document is a standalone document, I'd try something like the following (not tested), with $server, $dbname, $file, and $baseurl defined as environment variables:

> (echo CREATE DATABASE ${dbname}; 
>   echo ADD TO ${baseurl};
>   cat ${file};
>   echo EXIT ) | basexclient -n myserver -d -w

But otherwise I'd use the BaseX HTTP server and use curl or wget to sent a PUT request with the file to the address `http://myserver.example.org:8984/webdav/mydb/myfile.xml` (and of course, if necessary, I'd use curl multiple times to make the database and then add data to it).